# Factoring a number in the format $2^x + 2^y...$, etc.

Tags: exponentiation, factoring

Lets say I have this number: $4294967296$. I can easily convert it to $2^{32}$.

Now lets say I have this number: $33554688$. How could I factor it into $2^{25} + 2^8$? 
It needs to always be in the format of ($2$ to the power of $x$).

From my understanding every number could be factored into this format(unless it's odd then it would need a $+1$ at the end).

Comment: Are you just asking how to write a number in base $2$?

Comment: $2^0 =1$ so odd numbers can also be expressed in binary.

Comment: This is not called "factoring" it is called converting a number to [binary representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number). If you think it's easy for 4294967296, then I'm a bit surprised you don't have any ideas about how to convert your method to work for numbers that aren't powers of 2.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a faster method than this, but this method should work.

First, let's call your target number $N$. Start by finding the largest power of $2$ that is less than or equal to $N$, which in this case is $2^{25}=33554432$. Finding that first power of $2$ might be a little tedious if you do it by hand, but there are ways around that. Once you've found that power of $2$, subtract it from $N$ and repeat the process.

In this case, you find that $N-2^{25}=256$, which is clearly recognizable as $2^8$. Then you can rewrite the last equation and solve for $N$, and you're done:

\begin{align}
N-2^{25}&=256 \\
N-2^{25}&=2^8 \\
N&=2^{25}+2^8
\end{align}